# Random number loop program - javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like my program to return 10 random numbers but it isn't working it doesn't load the random numbers, I have linked the program to `index.html` so that's not the problem here, this is what I have tried:

```
function randomNumber(upper) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * upper) + 1;
}
var counter = 0;
while (counter < 10) {
    var randNum = randomNumber(6);
    document.write(randNum + ' ');
    counter += 1;
}
```

Comment: So what does "it isn't working" mean? Are you waiting for `onload`?

Comment: meaning it doesnt load the random numbers

Comment: maybe you are printing the results in the header of the page ...

Comment: ill add the index. html and style sheet too

Comment: i added it to js fiddle and it worked but for some reason it doesn't work on teamTreehouse (its the site im learning javascript from)

Answer (score 1):

If it works in fiddle but not elsewhere it's most probably a problem with `onload` here as Doorknob already suggested.

```
function randomNumber(upper) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * upper ) + 1;
}
window.onload = function () {
  var counter = 0;
  while (counter < 10) {
    var randNum = randomNumber(6);
    document.write(randNum + ' ');
    counter += 1;
  }
};
```

The bracketing with `window.onload` causes the code to wait until the whole page is loaded.